# How to get element content in table but outside tr tag in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Data I received from database, Postgresql, is html content for rendering in browser, it is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CU0012</td>
            <td>David</td>
            <td>Jonh</td>
        </tr>
        untitle Name <!-- content I would like retrieve and manipulate -->
        <tr>
            <td>CU0010</td>
            <td>Siv</td>
            <td>Hellen</td>
        ></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CU0009</td>
            <td>Merry</td>
            <td>Mug</td>
        ></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible that I want to be able to get text `untitle Name` that is in table but outside of `tr` tag so that I can manipulate it thereafter?

As a mater of fact, after this html script rendered in browser, any content that is not wrap properly in table would be forced to get outside of table, yet before it rendering I would like to keep there by access to it and make it properly wrap into table.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        htmlTable = $('table tr').html();
        htmlTable.each(function(){
        // check element is in tr or not
        });
    })
</script>
```

How can I archive that in jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying to get that content with jQuery - you should either remove it from the table or insert it into a td / tr - the ONLY valid children of a table are trs - with td's that house the content. Text outside of a TR but within a table element is not valid markup.

Comment: You could try adding it to a span and giving it an id?

Comment: When you receive this html text, you can remove it or replace with regex like `\</tr>\S+<tr>\` before load into html element.

Comment: @gavgrif yeah I would like to be able to access it so that I can I insert tr and td tag to it, since this data is retrieved from database table I could not change it manually, only use jquery script to change it before it rendering. Thanks

Comment: @Sphinx could you give example to make it an answer to I can test it out. Thanks

Comment: @DannyMoshe yes it is, but how I could not access it because it is already not in any Dom, this data is received from database table. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have invalid HTML? Seems like fixing invalid HTML would make this easier.... Browser is going to render that text outside of the table....

Comment: @gavgrif `caption`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` and `colgroup` are also valid children of `table`.

Comment: @connexo - fair point - but one element that is NOT a valid child is naked text

Comment: Sure, and your have a good point in your comment, but your claim ***the ONLY valid children of a table are trs - with td's that house the content*** is double-wrong. a) as aforementioned, b) text can also be in `th` and `caption` tags. Please try to be more precise next time you are making a strong claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When receive html content by ajax or other method, you can use `String.prototype.replace()` to remove the unexpected html content or replace with expected content before load it into one html element.

```js
//for example, you receive below text from the server
var serverData = '<table border="1"><tr><td>CU0012</td><td>David</td><td>Jonh</td></tr>untitle name<tr><td>CU0010</td><td>Siv</td><td>Hellen</td></tr></table>';

function loadReviseHtml(){
  var reviseData = serverData.replace(/<\/tr>\s*(.+)\s*<tr>/, '</tr><tr><td style="background-color:red">$1</td></tr><tr>');
  console.log(reviseData)
  document.getElementById('htmlcontainer1').innerHTML = reviseData;
}

function loadOrgHtml(){
  document.getElementById('htmlcontainer1').innerHTML = serverData;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="loadReviseHtml()" style="background-color:green;">Click me to load revised html!</a>
<div id="htmlcontainer1" style="background-color:gray;">
No Data!
</div>

<a onclick="loadOrgHtml()" style="background-color:red;">Click me to load org html!</a>
```

Comment: after testing and apply this to my real data, it's working flawlessly, Thanks very much  :)